# Theoretical performance comparison of querying database by file path vs. NTFS file ID

Tags: sql, database, windows, sqlite, winapi

Let's say you're storing information in an SQLite database for all files/directories located within a given directory on the user's machine. There will be one record in the database for each file or directory.  You'll store the file's or directory's relative path to the root directory.  And the machine is assumed to be Windows NTFS, so you can also obtain and store a [file ID (GUID)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110228-00/?p=11363) for each file or directory.

Now let's say you're given a path for a file, and you need to look up its info in the database.  Will it theoretically be more efficient to perform the look up by path or by file GUID?

On the one hand, obtaining the GUID will require calling `CreateFile` and `DeviceIoControl` (along with `CopyMemory` and `StringFromGUID2`, according to Raymond's method).

On the other hand, the file GUID string obtained might be much shorter than the file path, so I'm wondering if the database lookup could wind up being more efficient with the GUID.  Specifically, if the path at issue is a highly nested directory with a lot of files, then there would be a number of entries in the database with long, highly similar paths. So I'm wondering if the path lookup would be slow as a result.

I think indexing could occur on either the GUID string or the file path.

Does anyone have any thoughts on or experience with this?  Thanks for any input.

Comment: If you are calling `StringFromGUID2` you can't be interested in performance. You already have a GUID, with a size known at compile time, that's always shorter than its equivalent string representation. You've just turned what used to be two register compares into a `memcmp`.

Comment: why in this case not use ntfs file id (64bit) (not guid) ? this will be fastest

Comment: @RbMM - So to clarify, are you saying to store the object ID as a blob or an integer in the SQLite database?

Comment: if you want use GUID for files - why in this case already not use file id (8 bytes) - this more simply and faster compare guid

Comment: @RbMm I just did some testing, and I don't think the file id stays consistent over time, unlike the GUID.

Comment: if you not recreate file (delete and create new with some name) id not changed

Comment: NTFS is probably faster in general (there was some Microsoft article about that and also about the defunct "WinFS" long time ago) however it maybe not super optimized to get a file by its id as it's not a so common usage. Testing is your best bet. PS: file id and guid (with upper bytes filled with extra 0, represented by the union in FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR ) are the same for NTFS. You can get it using command line `fsutil file queryfileid <filepath>`

Comment: @SimonMourier - i mean [`this`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_internal_information) as file id. (query by call [`NtQueryInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryinformationfile) ) with *FileInternalInformation*. really low 48 bit this is index of mft record and high 16 bit - reuse record number. not think that can be something faster than use direct index in array. and this is not changed until file not deleted